# Azure Resource Graph query to find all VMs with public IPs

Tags: azure, resources

Trying to get a list of all virtual machines in all subscriptions that have a public IP attached.

Historically I've had to run two separate queries:

```
az graph query -q "where type =~ 'microsoft.network/publicipaddresses' | project tenantId, subscriptionId, properties.ipAddress, name, id, properties.dnsSettings.fqdn, properties.ipConfiguration.id" --output tsv --first 5000 > ips.csv
```

and

```
az graph query -q "where type =~ 'microsoft.network/networkInterfaces' | project name, id, properties.virtualMachine.id, properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.publicIPAddress.id, properties.networkSecurityGroup.id" --output tsv --first 5000 > networks.csv
```

However, that gives me results that take forever to format in Excel, with trims, vlookups, etc.

Really struggling here.  I'm a rookie at Resource Graph, and am playing in the explorer.  I can get lists of VMs, I can get lists of NICs, I can get lists of public IPs, but having trouble putting them together :(

Comment: Can you use other CLI commands or only the `az graph`? And what the info of the vMyou want to get?

Comment: I can run other commands, but trying to use Resource Graph, as going through subscriptions iteratively using a for loop takes a LONG time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're only after ARM (Azure Resource Manager) VMs, you can use the Azure Resource Graph query below to get all the VMs along with all their public and private IPs, provided the machine has at least one public IP. Unlike the one currently present in the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced?tabs=azure-cli#join-vmpip), the one below will work for multiple IPs, whether due to multiple vmNics or multiple IP configurations per vmNic.

A sample of the output:

[image]

The ARG query:

```
Resources
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
    | project vmId = tolower(tostring(id)), vmName = name
    | join (Resources
        | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/networkinterfaces'
        | mv-expand ipconfig=properties.ipConfigurations
        | project vmId = tolower(tostring(properties.virtualMachine.id)), privateIp = ipconfig.properties.privateIPAddress, publicIpId = tostring(ipconfig.properties.publicIPAddress.id)
        | join kind=leftouter (Resources
            | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/publicipaddresses'
            | project publicIpId = id, publicIp = properties.ipAddress
        ) on publicIpId
        | project-away publicIpId, publicIpId1
        | summarize privateIps = make_list(privateIp), publicIps = make_list(publicIp) by vmId
    ) on vmId
    | project-away vmId1
    | sort by vmName asc
| where array_length(publicIps)>0
```

The direct link to Azure Resource Graph Explorer with the query above is [here](https://portal.azure.com/?feature.customportal=false#blade/HubsExtension/ArgQueryBlade/query/Resources%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20where%20type%20%3D%7E%20%27microsoft.compute%2Fvirtualmachines%27%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20project%20vmId%20%3D%20tolower%28tostring%28id%29%29%2C%20vmName%20%3D%20name%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20join%20%28Resources%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20where%20type%20%3D%7E%20%27microsoft.network%2Fnetworkinterfaces%27%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20mv-expand%20ipconfig%3Dproperties.ipConfigurations%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20project%20vmId%20%3D%20tolower%28tostring%28properties.virtualMachine.id%29%29%2C%20privateIp%20%3D%20ipconfig.properties.privateIPAddress%2C%20publicIpId%20%3D%20tostring%28ipconfig.properties.publicIPAddress.id%29%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20join%20kind%3Dleftouter%20%28Resources%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20where%20type%20%3D%7E%20%27microsoft.network%2Fpublicipaddresses%27%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20project%20publicIpId%20%3D%20id%2C%20publicIp%20%3D%20properties.ipAddress%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%29%20on%20publicIpId%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20project-away%20publicIpId%2C%20publicIpId1%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%7C%20summarize%20privateIps%20%3D%20make_list%28privateIp%29%2C%20publicIps%20%3D%20make_list%28publicIp%29%20by%20vmId%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%29%20on%20vmId%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%7C%20project-away%20vmId1%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%7C%20sort%20by%20vmName%20asc%0A%7C%20where%20array_length%28publicIps%29%3E0).

Details of how a query very similar to this is built step-by-step can be found [here](https://mihai-albert.com/2020/10/01/get-the-list-of-all-azure-vms-with-all-their-private-and-public-ips/#ARM). If you're looking for "classic" Azure ASM (Azure Service Manager) VMs, an ARG query for them is described in the same article [here](https://mihai-albert.com/2020/10/01/get-the-list-of-all-azure-vms-with-all-their-private-and-public-ips/#ASM).